# Make Qt Font color always contrast with background. (black or white)

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm working on a custom Qt widget for a 'sanity' tool, after running the check, the header color of my widget that contain a QLabel will change. My current problem is that I would like to have my label color change from black to white relative to the background color.

What I also want to do is something like the fusion style offer, if my header if only half filled, the text will be black and white to contrast with the background. (Really cool for a QProgressBar)

I've currently tried to do this by testing with some CSS example but I don't really know how CSS works and it seems to be different into Qt stylesheet.

Of course, i've mostly tried to do this through stylesheet but I would like to understand how to do it with QPalette.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Could you explain me better ?, maybe an image or gif helps you understand yourself better

Comment: https://ddgobkiprc33d.cloudfront.net/7c51c428-735a-476d-95b0-da06e90f28d3.png

One of my main goal is to only have a widget that subclass QLabel and who can automatically adjust its color from its parent background. (For the calculation I found this: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx)

If the parent color brightess is to high the text will be black, and if the brightness is low, the color will be black.
I would also want to be able to draw the label half black/white if the background color is not solid.

Comment: What do you mean *parent color*? Do you mean background color?

Comment: Yes the parent background color, sorry for the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is drawn directly in the widget (like in a `QProgressBar`), you just have to deal with the color used to draw the background. It's quite easy with a `QPainter` and `QPainter::setClipPath` method:

```
class ProgressBar(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progression = 0
        self.startTimer(200)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        text = "This is a text"
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 24))

        boundingRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        progressionRect = boundingRect.adjusted(0, 0, - self.width() * (1 - self.progression), 0)
        leftRect = boundingRect.adjusted(progressionRect.width(), 0, 0, 0)

        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(progressionRect)

        painter.setClipRect(leftRect)
        painter.drawText(boundingRect, Qt.AlignCenter,text)
        painter.setPen(Qt.white)
        painter.setClipRect(progressionRect)
        painter.drawText(boundingRect, Qt.AlignCenter, text)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        self.progression = min(1.0, self.progression + 0.02)
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = ProgressBar()
    p.resize(640, 480)
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Since, your label is another widget in the header, you have to find the right color. If the label knows that its parent is your header (and you have the good accessor in the progression value), you can reuse the solution above.

If you need a generic way to draw a label on a widget by inverting the color, you could draw the parents render in a image, invert the colors and use it to paint the text.

A quick example as explanation:

```
class Window(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progression = 0

        self.startTimer(200)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        boundingRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height() * self.progression)

        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(boundingRect)



    def timerEvent(self, event):
        self.progression = min(1.0, self.progression + 0.02)
        self.update()



class ContrastedText(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, text="", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text = text


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 24))
        boundingRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        fm = QFontMetrics(painter.font())
        textBoundingRect = fm.boundingRect(boundingRect, Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)

        # No parent. The text is black
        if not self.parent():
            painter.drawText(boundingRect, Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)
            return

        # Get the parents render and invert its color to have the good constrast
        render = QPixmap(self.parent().size()).toImage()
        self.parent().render(render, QPoint(), QRegion(), QWidget.DrawWindowBackground)
        render.invertPixels(QImage.InvertRgba)

        # Define a clip path containing the text and draw the image
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addText(textBoundingRect.topLeft(), painter.font(), self.text)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawImage(-self.mapTo(self.parent(), QPoint(0, 0)), render)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
    label = ContrastedText("This is a text")

    layout.addWidget(label)
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Romha, but from what I tried with you example, you fill a background ?
What I would like to do is having a common QLabel that I can parent into a custom QProgressBar or a QWidget and who will adapt its color from the color behind (parent background color).

I will do more tests using the paintEvent, I've actually only tried with stylesheet and QPalette.

Comment: In my second example, I created a dummy widget `window` that changes its background like a progress bar and a label `ContrastedLabel` which adpats the text color to its parent rendering. You can use `ContrastedLabel` in most of widgets, actually